# Appcelerator - Sqlite on windows phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to make a basic Appcelerator app with a collection and models work on a windows phone, but I am not able to use the "fetch" method on the collection, the app crashes.
I have read that SQLite is not available on windows phone, is it right?
If yes, how can I manage to make it work with Appcelerator?
I have seen that there is an SQLite librairy available which must be included in Visual studio, useless in my case.

Has someone already faced this issue?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: SQLite is available for windows phone. Here is a blog: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps

Comment: You can use sqlite for windows phone silverlight 8 apps, windows phone 8.1 apps, UWP (Universal Windows Platform) and Windows 10 / Windows 10 Mobile apps. Google can be very helpful to start your app.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this works only with Visual Studio, right? I'm working with the Appcelerator Titanium framework and their dedicated IDE (Appcelerator Studio), so how can I integrated SQLite (if necessary)? I'm new to mobile app development...

Answer (score 0):

Titanium for Windows support SQLite via [Ti.Database](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it supports SQLITE in windowsphone too..

To fetch single record please use

```
var oUser =  Alloy.createModel('user');

oUser.fetch({UserId : uId});
```

To fetch collection of records please use

```
var _speaker = Alloy.Collections.speaker;

_speaker.fetch(); 

var _speaker = Alloy.Collections.speaker;
_speaker.fetch();
```